# reactjs, webpack 3+, babel, with IIS 8+ - Where do I point IIS to serve up the dist folder for deployment?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, iis, webpack, babeljs

I have constructed a website using a react/webpack dev-server. I want to deploy the site to the web server now. I have cloned the project from github to the server. I have created a new website and app pool in iis and set the basic path to the website folder where my index.html file is. I run the npm start command which concurrently launches the dev server (port 8081) and the node.js server (port 5000) .... I can see the dev server with no issue when I go to localhost:8081 but when I go to localhost:8080 the page times out and displays a

```
Bad Request - Invalid Hostname

HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.
```

error message. Can someone tell me whats wrong with my web.config file and why IIS won't proxy the node server and dist folder? (I am using url rewrite)

Here is my webpack.config (located in root folder):

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8081',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|ttf|svg|eot)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
      }
    ],
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
  ]
};
```

Here is the server.js (located in /server/core/ folder):

```
const webpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const config = require('../../webpack.config.js');
const options = {
  contentBase: './dist',
  hot: true
};

var app = require('express')();
var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')


webpackDevServer.addDevServerEntrypoints(config, options);
const compiler = webpack(config);
const server = new webpackDevServer(compiler, options);

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
  console.log('dev server listening on port 5000');
});
```

and finally here is the web.config file (located in the root folder):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="/\server/\core/\server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/\server/\core/\server.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Finally Here is my folder structure:

[image: folder structure]

Comment: did you create a distribution by runnning `npm run build`?

Comment: yes, but the index.html file is in the root folder and the bundle.js file is in the dist

Comment: This feels like a syntax issue but I cannot be sure

Comment: check the edit I just made, thanks

Comment: Your index.html and bundled asset files should be in the same place. Sounds like you need to use the [HTML webpack plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) to auto bundle them together.

Comment: Chase, can you add an answer with a sample packag.json and the added code for the webpack.config as an answer? I will try to implement it after lunch. Thanks

Comment: OK so I installed the HTML webpack plugin but I am still having the same issues